# Android : Updating row layouts based on User Input with a CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-cursoradapter

I am currently working on an Application wich displays data from a SQLiteDatabase in a listview. This listview is using custom layouts. My intent was to have three different layouts, depending on what the user is doing. The first layout only displays one TextView and a Button (called row_nameonly). If the user presses this button, the layout would switch to a more detailed view (called row_viewentry). Finnaly, if the user presses the button again, the first layout is displayed once more (row_nameonly). I have tried to accomplish this, but have not found a working solution. My current version seems to change the View of the row, but the new layout is not visible. I wish to do this without having to add extra data to the database.
This is the code of the Custom CursorAdapter :

```
public class EntryListCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

public int viewRequestPosition = -100;

public EntryListCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_nameonly, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();

    if(cursor.getPosition() == viewRequestPosition){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_viewentry, parent, false);
    }

    if(!(cursor.getPosition() == viewRequestPosition)) {
        TextView nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        ImageButton expandMoreButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_expandmore);

        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("prename")) + " " +
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("surname"));

        nameView.setText(name);

        expandMoreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewRequestPosition = cursor.getPosition();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

TLDR: Is there a way to have the CursorAdapter change the layout of the view in wich the button was clicked, and have the new layout displayed, without adding extra data to the SQLiteDatabase ?

Thank you
(If you need any more information please ask)

Comment: Given what you have shared with us, I suggest you create a single layout with the "view_entry" parts invisible. Only when the "cursor.getPosition() == viewRequestPosition" in bindView, then make those parts visible and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is curious,
I had the Adapter take the Fragment calling it in its constructor. Then i saved the position of the ListItems i wanted to change the layout of in the fragment wich called the adapter. Then i created a new instance of the adapter, but this time the layout would changed based on the positions i saved in the fragment.